# Disabling Java Agents

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04

Currently running a server that provides some of the Atlasian tools (Crucible, fisheye, jira), I want, for security reasons to disable ANY Java agents execution on the server.

My point is not disabling agents that can be launched with the application through the `-javaagent` CLI parameter, but agents that can be dynamically attached to the running instance (see for example byteman). Ie, make the Java applications not "attachable".

Another constraint is that it is some kind hard to modify those tools command line due to configuration complexity. So, the change would have to be global, for the complete server, for all the Java applications.

Is there any way to globally disable this "feature"? Through Java config, or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [this forum post](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/60197-disable-attach-api-sun-jvm.html), this depends on the JVM in question:

IBM JVM:

```
java -Dcom.ibm.tools.attach.enable=false [...]
```

SUN/Oracle JVM/OpenJDK:

```
java -XX:+DisableAttachMechanism [...]
```

More information on Java VM parameters can be found [here](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html)

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html) suggests that an environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` can be used to force these options system wide. This might not work with all JVMs though.

Comment: This is to be added in the Java launch CL, I suppose? Is there a way to make it applied to any Java application? By using a config file, for example.

Comment: @HeisSpiter I updated my answer

Comment: OK, works! Ty :-)